# Separação de tabelas em html

Tags: html, tabela-html

Eu criei 4 tabelas, mas quero separá-las e não consigo, elas estão todas pegadas.
Como posso resolver isto?
Vou deixar o código.
Ao correr elas não aparecem lado a lado por ser um espaço pequeno mas dá para ver a primeira e a segunda tabela.

```css
.table, th, td {
  border: solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 3px;
}

.th, td {
  border-width: 3px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <tr>
    <table align="left" class="table" style="width:10%">
      <tr>
        <th align="center" bgcolor="#def2d9" colspan="3">1 STARTER</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Users</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M00</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td>Base Package</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SP40</td>
        <td align="center">NA</td>
        <td>Training</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="3">
          <p class="left">
            <b>PRICE:</b>
            <span class"right" align="right">9 900,00€<br>+<br>131,67€<br>Monthly Subscription</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table align="left" class="table" style="width:15%" "float:left">
      <tr>
        <th align="center" bgcolor="#ffe5d5" colspan="3">2 PRODUCTION BASICS</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Users</th> 
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M00</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td>Base Package</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M12a</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td>Technical Drawings</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M13</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td>BOM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>V-PRO</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td>Cutting Optimization Drawings</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SP60</td>
        <td align="center">NA</td>
        <td>Training</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="3">
          <p class="left">
            <b>PRICE:</b>
            <span class="right" align="right">17 650,00€<br>+<br>244,17€<br>Monthly Subscription</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table align="left" class="table" style="width:15%" "float:left">
      <tr>
        <th align="center" bgcolor="#fff4ca" colspan="4">3 PRODUCTION MACHINES</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Users</th>
        <th>Machines</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M00</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Base Package</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M12a</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Technical Drawings</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M12b</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td>CNC Machine's Comunication</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M13</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>BOM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>V-PRO PP</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td>Cutting Optimization Panel Saw's Comunication</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SP80</td>
        <td align="center">NA</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Training</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="4">
          <p class="left">
            <b>PRICE:</b>
            <span class="right" align="right">21 620,00€<br>+<br>293,67€<br>Monthly Subscription</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table align="left" class="table" style="width:15%" "float:left">
      <tr>
        <th align="center" bgcolor="#dcebf8" colspan="5"> 4 PRODUCTION COMPLETE</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Users</th>
        <th>Machines</th>
        <th>SF Centers</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M00</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Base Package</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M03</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Auto Item Generation</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M10</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Package Optimization</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M11</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Group different order's components</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M12a</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Technical Drawings</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M12b</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>CNC Machine's Comunication</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>M13</td>
        <td align="center">up to 3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>BOM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>V-PRO PP</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Cutting Optimization Panel Saw's Comunication</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Psmart</td>
        <td align="center">1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">4</td>
        <td>Shop Floor Control</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SP120</td>
        <td align="center">NA</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Training</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="5">
          <p class="left">
            <b>PRICE:</b>
            <span class="right" align="right">35 090,00€<br>+<br>583,79€<br>Monthly Subscription</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer que apareça uma ao lado da outra, com um espaço maior?

Comment: @ArturTrapp sim, elas têm de estar lado a lado, mas com espaçamento entre elas, não coladas como estão. Consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu coloquei um pequeno espaçamento à direita delas apenas adicionando no topo do seu CSS a seguinte linha:

```
table { margin-right: 10px; }
```

Coloquei um exemplo no JSFiddle pra você ver e editar como quiser:

https://jsfiddle.net/p0jp370L/4/

Comment: basta pôr no css?

Comment: @MelissaSousa sim, só fazer isso

Comment: no seu exeplo no jsfiddle realmente está como quero, mas eu apliquei e não resultou

Comment: @MelissaSousa experimente colocar o  `margin-right: 10px;` dentro do .table, do jeito que eu atualizei no exemplo

Comment: foi como fiz, eu copiei e colei exatamente como você tem

Comment: @MelissaSousa Isso é estranho. Você salvou e apertou `ctrl+f5`? E dá uma olhada no fiddle de novo, eu mudei uma coisa

Comment: sim fiz isso tudo, irei ver novamente

Comment: ainda nada :/ não sei que fazer mais

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55971/discussion-between-artur-trapp-and-melissa-sousa).

Comment: como vou para o chat? Sou nova por aqui

Comment: Só clica no link que tá ali

Answer (score 0):

Use a propriedade margin do CSS

```
.table{

        margin:top, right, bottom, and left;

 }
```

> Defina os valores que você deseja